# Editor save preference option

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In General -> Editors there is a preference "Prompt to save on close even if still open elsewhere". What is the exact purpose of this preference check box? If I un-check it and close workbench that has XML based dirty editor, it bypasses the message "...still open elsewhere" and asks me to save the editors anyway.

[image]

The issue I am having is with a save dialog when closing workbench with unsaved changes. Here is STR:

1. Create XSD Schema and open in Schema Editor
2. Add arbitrary element and close workbench (don't save editor)

I get the following dialog about 'Propeties' not being saved. Why does Eclipse differentiate Properties from the main editor even though it's the same model I presume? If I uncheck the preference checkbox, I don't get this dialog, but only one about editor not saved.

[image]

Comment: It's a preference page for **Editors**.

Comment: I know, but what's the purpose of this check box if it asks user to save editor, similar message about unsaved changes is displayed if this preference is not checked. I am asking because some of our users got confused about nature of this preference, and I don't understand myself its purpose. It's seems to be triggered by XML based editors.

Comment: Your use case was closing the entire workbench. This option affects the scenario where you've opened a file with one editor, opened it with another editor, modified it, and then close one of those editors.

Comment: That's the thing - there is only one editor. Unless with XML based editors it's somewhat different behavior?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be, but was the file open elsewhere in Eclipse? That's the only time it would act differently.

Comment: I'll update OP with repro details

Comment: For the XML Schema editor, I'm not sure.

Comment: XML Schema Editor was just an example. This happens with other editors as well. Should I open bugzilla for this to see if there is an issue with persisting resources? If so, in which category?

Comment: As long as this isn't about behavior when closing Eclipse itself and it affects multiple file types, Platform UI is where to start.